# SOLR df and qf explanation

Tags: search, solr

I cannot find an adequeate explanation of how these query params interact

I am getting suprising (to me) results that if I specify

```
qf=title^20 description^10
```

then I get no results
however if I then add

```
df=description
```

I do get results

df is set to text in solrconfig.xml - which will change - but my question is this - does the df setting somehow override the qf setting?  this seems odd

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`df` is the default field and will only take effect if the `qf` is not defined.

I guess you are not using dismax parser and using the default settings in `solrconfig.xml`

`qf` then won't take effect anyways and the `df` field which is `text` would not return values.

`df=description` searches on the field and hence returns values.
Try passing `defType=edismax` as parameter.

Comment: great - trying to ensure I am using edismax by default is exactly why I have started to look at this - guess I need to tweak solrconfig.xml

Answer (score 3):

The `df` stands for `default field`, while the `qf` stands for `query fields`.

The field defined by the `df` parameter is used when no fields are mentioned in the query. For example if you are running a query like `q=solr` and you have `df=title` the query itself will actually be `title:solr`. The `df` parameter is supported by the default Solr request handler.

The `qf` parameter is something used by the `dismax` query parser and the `edismax` query parser. You probably don't have the `defType=dismax` or `defType=edismax` added to your request handler parameters or to your query. Try adding it and you should get the search results.