# Solr result difference between "field:query string" and using "df"

Tags: dataframe, solr

I have a solr core with names and some meta data. 
Something like this: "firstname"; "lastname"; "search"; "meta1"; "meta2"; etc.

Where "search" is a copy field containing "firstname" and "lastname". Search looks like this: **search: ["johhny", "cash"]**.
The schema *default field* is the "search" field.

When I search only over query wtih "firstname:johnny" I get different results compared to a search over the default field "df = firstname" and query "johnny".

Can anyone explain why this is and what the inner workings are for this effect?

Comment: Checkout [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17363921/1592845) and check your `solorconfig.xml` according it.

Comment: So basically doing firstname:searchString still takes the default schema defined field "search" into account, whereas using the df=firstname only takes into account the "firstname" field? 

From my tests it seems to be like that.

Comment: Doing a search only with "searchString" and one with "firstname:searchString" delivers the same results. The score is different though.

Comment: The is no definition for the "qf" in the schema.

Comment: Note that the `df` tag is for the Unix command by that name and has nothing to do with dataframes.