# Query with q=*:* && q={keyword} && q=field:{keyword} in solr 4.9

Tags: tomcat, solr, solr4

- I've just found about apache solr, and after i installed apache Solr with Tomcat successfully. And i began to use Apache Solr to search.
- But i had some problem with results of Apache Solr.
- When i query a field same as: `title: love`, and URL was same as:

  - `http://my_ip:8080/solr/music/select?q=title%3A+love&wt=json&indent=true` .
  - Apache Solr returned **a lot of results** with `title` match with word `love`.
- The problem here if i query same as: `love`, and URL was same as:

  - `http://my_ip:8080/solr/music/select?q=love&wt=json&indent=true`
  - Apache Solr **didn't return any results**.

**I want to ask why`q=love` didn't return any results ?** Hope that everybody can help me. Thank you very much.

This is my `schema.xml` file:

```xml
<schema name="example" version="1.5">
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="title" type="text_vi" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="type_music" type="text_vi" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_is" type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_ss" type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_ls" type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_en"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_bs" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_fs" type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_ds" type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>

<!-- Type used to index the lat and lon components for the "location" FieldType -->
<dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false" />

<dynamicField name="*_dt"  type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_dts" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_p"  type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<!-- some trie-coded dynamic fields for faster range queries -->
<dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_tf" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

<dynamicField name="*_c"   type="currency" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

<dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="attr_*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />

<!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
<fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
<fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

And this is my `solrconfig.xml` file:

```xml
<luceneMatchVersion>4.9</luceneMatchVersion>
<lib dir="../../../contrib/analysis-extras/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="/home/my_name/apache_solr/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/dist" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-4.9.0.jar" />
<lib dir="/home/my_name/apache_solr/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/dist" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-extras-4.9.0.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../lib" regex="mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar" />
```

And this is `data-config.xml` file:

```xml
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"  driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/sieunhac_development"  user="root"  password=""/>
<document name="musics">
<entity name="musics" pk="id"
  query="select p.id, LCASE(p.title) as title, birthday_singer, p.type_music from musics p order by updated_at desc;">
  <field column="id" name="id" template="id"/>
  <field column="title" name="title"/>

  <field name="type_music" column="type_music" />
</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your `solrconfig.xml` file, you will see that the **/select** `requestHandler` is configured with the default search field as:

```xml
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="df">name</str>
</lst>
```

Here, you can put the field that you want like for example:

```xml
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="df">title</str>
</lst>
```

You  can see another topic about [this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363677/solr-df-and-qf-explanation) and the [Solr Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#df).

**UPDATE**

To answer to your comment, in your `schema.xml`, you can create a new field:

```xml
<field name="searchable_field" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true" />
```

After that, you can copy the fields that you want in your new field:

```xml
<copyField source="title" dest="searchable_field"/>
<copyField source="author" dest="searchable_field"/>
<copyField source="production" dest="searchable_field"/>
```

And to finish, you just have to put this new field in your `solrconfig.xml`:

```xml
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="df">searchable_field</str>
</lst>
```

Comment: I've just tried and it worked very well. Thank you very much.
By the way if i want to search not only `field title` but also other fields (combine). Are there any solutions ?

Comment: Great. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, your answer was very clear. One again, thank you very much.