# Solr Field does not return results

Tags: solr, solrj

Solr does not return the results until I prefix the :field name for example 
I am searching for Ajay,I need to prefix name:Ajay to get the results.I tried the copy tag.But it does not seem to return the results.Can you please tell me what can I change other than the below change.

```
<copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="last_name" dest="text"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old way this was configured was with `<defaultSearchField>` in schema.xml. This indicates the field searched by default if no other field is included in the query.

You may want to either use the `df` parameter in the query (or as the other answer says, add it as a default value), or if you're using the (e)dismax handler (which you probably are), use the `qf` parameter to indicate which fields to query and the weights between the different fields.

```
q=Ajay&qf=text&defType=edismax
```

.. should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your `solrconfig.xml` file, you will see that the **/select** `requestHandler` is configured with the default search field as:

```xml
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="df">aField</str>
</lst>
```

Here, you can put the field that you want like for example:

```xml
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="df">name</str>
</lst>
```

You  can see another topic about [this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363677/solr-df-and-qf-explanation) and the [Solr Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#df).

To build a searcheable field, in your `schema.xml`, you can create a new field:

```xml
<field name="searchable_field" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true" />
```

After that, you can copy the fields that you want in your new field:

```xml
<copyField source="name" dest="searchable_field"/>
<copyField source="last_name" dest="searchable_field"/>
<copyField source="birthday" dest="searchable_field"/>
<copyField source="location" dest="searchable_field"/>
```

And to finish, you just have to put this new field in your `solrconfig.xml`:

```xml
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="df">searchable_field</str>
</lst>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where do I place the snippet in solrconfig.xml?

Comment: In your **requestHandler** called `/select` !

Comment: In your **solrconfig.xml**, what is the default field `df`? What **requestHandler** are you using? What exactly is your request?